Compute $\|x_n(t)-x(t)\|_1$, issue about calculation
For all $n\in \mathbb{N^\ast}$, let be $x_n: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:
$$x_n(t)= \begin{cases} 1, & 0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\\ n\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right), & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \\ -1, &\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\leq t\leq 1 \end{cases}
$$
For $n\to +\infty$, the pointwise limit of the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is the function $x:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:
$$x(t)=\begin{cases} 1, & 0\leq t< \frac{1}{2}\\ 0, & t=\frac{1}{2} \\ -1, &\frac{1}{2}< t\leq 1 \end{cases}$$
Now, I have to compute $$\|x_n-x\|_1=\int_0^1 |x_n(t)-x(t)| \ dt=$$ $$=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}|1-1|\ dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left|n\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)-1\right|\ dt +  $$ $$+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\left|n\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)+1\right|\ dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}^1|-1+1|\ dt=$$
The first and the fourth integrals are zero because the integrand is zero, so it remains that:
$$=\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{2}-nt-1\right)\ dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\left(\frac{n}{2}-nt+1\right)\ dt=\Bigl[\frac{nt}{2}-\frac{nt^2}{2}-t\Bigl]_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}+\Bigl[\frac{nt}{2}-\frac{nt^2}{2}+t\Bigl]^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}_{\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{n}{8}-\frac{1}{2}-\left[\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]+$$ $$+\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{n}{4}-\frac{n}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{n}{8}-\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left[\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)-1\right]+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left[\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)+1\right]-\frac{n}{8}-\frac{1}{2}=$$
Adding the terms out of all brackets:
$$=-1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$=-1-\left(\frac{n}{8}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)+\left(\frac{n}{8}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=0$$
But, according to my teacher,  the correct result is $\frac{1}{n}$ instead, that tends to zero for $n\to +\infty$.
What am I doing wrong?
My professor used this example to prove that the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the norm $\|.\|_1$ is not complete as a metric space.

"What am I doing wrong?"
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left|n\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)-1\right|\ dt=\color{red}-\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{2}-nt-1\right)\ dt.$$
Keeping track of this correction along your subsequent calculations leads to your teacher's result:
$$\color{red}{-\frac n4+}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac1n.$$
